# Undefined symbols error while building PhoneGap under Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cordova

I'm trying to build a PhoneGap-based application using Xcode 4. Since there's no PhoneGap project template for Xcode 4, I used [the handy web page](https://build.phonegap.com/generate) to create the project. However, I'm getting the following error when I build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PhoneGapDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TestAppDelegate in TestAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PhoneGapDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TestAppDelegate in TestAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The bulk of the Cocoa Touch code for a PhoneGap app is built as a library called PhoneGapLib. The application project references the PhoneGapLib project and depends on and links with its product, PhoneGapLib.a. PhoneGapDelegate is defined in PhoneGapLib; TestAppDelegate is defined in the main project. I've set the Valid Architectures setting for both the main project and the PhoneGapLib project to "armv6 armv7 i386".

I don't know what's causing the error above. Can anyone decipher it and tell me which build settings I should be looking at to resolve it?

I found [a Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/544f44883f9e22b6) in which the author solves a similar problem by using lipo to manually combine different builds of the library. I'd really like to avoid that step if possible -- this seems like something that I should be able to accomplish with the right combination of build settings in the two projects.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't know how to resolve the linker error described above, I was able to work around it by creating a new project using the web page linked above. I also downloaded PhoneGap 0.95, a 0.01 upgrade from my previous version. I don't know which of these two actions fixed the problem, but I'm now able to build a PhoneGap app without the problem above. Also, someone pointed out that there are now some [beta PhoneGap templates available for Xcode 4](http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/05/05/phonegap-xcode-4-template/).

Answer (score 2):

0.9.5.1 release includes Xcode 4 templates.